# How to format string in gridview in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am fetching Two Columns from database, one column has data type as varbinary.
I am converting the varbinary column to byte[] and then to string.
Code is working for console application and keeping the string format.
But when i am using the same code in Web Application and displaying the data in GridView, it losing the format. For Ex:

### Hello

World

will be displaying as Hello World in Grid View.
Here is my code :

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=legal; Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_output_repayment  @id=1", con);

    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Category");
    dt.Columns.Add("Description");

    while (dr.Read())
    {
    DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();

        dr1["Category"] = dr[0];
        dr1["Description"] = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString((byte[])dr[1]).Normalize();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr1);


    }

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
You should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - Also note that DataGridView != GridView

Comment: @TaW should ASP.NET since OP says *i am using the same code in Web Application and displaying the data in GridView*. Moreover there is no `DataBind()` in Winform

Comment: how about your GridView1

Comment: In a web page you should use br tag for a newline.

Comment: @Rahul: This information should be in a Tag and not hidden in the question!

Comment: @TaW Agree ... that comment is fyi

Comment: Just as a helpful hint... Naming your DataReader "dr", while naming your DataRow "dr1" will lead to confusion down the line.  Consider using another naming convention (like, for example, `DataRow row = table.NewRow();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are working on the asp.net side then you should use `DataBound` inside the gridview as well as setting `AutoGenerateColumns="false"`

Now it's my main point of view if you are getting description of whatever format as well then use `HtmlEncode="false"` for your column that you used

Few Code of GridView,that you will have to utilize as such format described.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" HtmlEncode="false" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Error format that I could faced using `HtmlEncode="true"` or removing it

[image]

Tested and got well using `HtmlEncode="false"` upon following result

[image]

Comment: Hi  Ali,
thanks for the answer.
did you make any changes in your code as well?

Comment: Don't add columns through code make a list or what you think is better but solution provided as well for your problem using HtmlEncode

Comment: it worked for me, 
With you code and little modification in code as as well,
Thanks. :)